# Azure internal load balancer not receiving frowarding request to vm

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, internal-load-balancer

I am having difficulties setting up my internal load balancer to process requests.

I have setup my vnet, vms, load balancer etc using this template

[Azure Resource manager template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/templates/201-2-vms-internal-load-balancer/)

one of the differences between the template and my setup is that i am using a different backend port.  I have setup the probe to also look at this port use this port aswell.

I have opened the port on each vm (windows 2012 R2 Datacenter).  I can successfully call one vm to the other using the vip.

I'm aware I can't call the internal load balancer from a virtual machine that is being load balanced, so i setup a third test vm sitting in the same vnet and region etc, when i try to call the load balancer fromhere i simply get a page not found.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Hi Figured out what was happening.  The setup was ok.  The problem turned out to be related to the probe setup. I had changed the probe to http and prvided it a url, but i forgot the url returns 301.  The ILB is looking for 200 only on these Probes otherwise it will throw the VM out of the pool.  To fix the issue i just went back to TCP probe on the VM  (backend) port.

Answer (score 0):

which port do you use? You may want to check your firewall on the VM and ensure your port is not blocked

Comment: Hi I have opened the port I need to use. If I fire up another vm within the vnet I can call the vm directly using the vm internal ip and the port, but if I fire a request to the ilb nothing happens.

Comment: Hi, would you mind sending your deploymentId and ARM template to Azurenetdocfeedback@microsoft.com? Will be happy to take a look and check your configuration

Comment: Hi unfortunately i had to scrap the ARM approach, i had problems integrating a point to site vnet with the Azure Web apps i have running.  I have created everything using the classic method now and i still ge tthe same issue.  I don't know much about how these load balancers work so i think im making the same mistake as before.

Comment: Feel free to send us your deploymentid and we can take a look

Comment: Hi Figured out what was happening.  The setup was ok.  The problem turned out to be related to the probe setup. I had changed the probe to http and prvided it a url, but i forgot the url returns 301.  The ILB is looking for 200 only on these Probes otherwise it will throw the VM out of the pool.  To fix the issue i just went back to TCP probe on the VM  (backend) port.